# Get single value from XML File in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to pull a single value from XML stored in a variable in a C# console application.
Here is my XML:

```
     string myxml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>                            
                          <params>
                           <rowsEffected>1</rowsEffected>
                          </params>
                          <data>
                            <rowData>
                              <row>
                                <answer>1234</answer>
                              </row>
                            </rowData>
                         </data>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(myxml);  //This is as far as I can get
```

I have read thru many tutorials but can't get this simple task.
I want to extract the value from the "answer" tag, so my result should be 1234
The XML will always have one record.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I fixed your question stop breaking it.

Comment: `I have read thru many tutorials but can't get this simple task` Really? SO is full of examples...

Comment: Yes, I should also add that I'm a junior level programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is invalid.  There can only be one root element.  In your XML `params` and `data` are both top level elements which is not allowed.  Try it out for yourself at: http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: Yup it fails, I'm using a another vendor's software package to export and this is the format it spits out in.  I'll talk to them.  Thanks.

Comment: @RichardHetherington - If you want to mark an answer as accepted click the check mark underneath the vote count and it will turn green.